# Spring JPA: How do we sort by an attribute present in an Embedded class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I tried searching for my issue on SO, but I couldn't find one matching my issue.
So lets take a simple example here wherein I have an entity class and an composite primary key (embedded) class.

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private String startDate;
    @Column(name = "stop_date")
    private String stopDate;
    @Column(name = "empId")
    private int empId;
    @Column(name = "ssn")
    private String ssn;
}
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "employee")
public class EmployeeEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId employeeId ;
    @Column(name = "fName")
    private String fName;
    @Column(name = "lName")
    private String lName;
}
```

Repository Class:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeEntity, EmployeeId> {
// The below method works and I can see the result sorted by first names
    List<EmployeeEntity> findByEmployeeId_EmpIdAndEmployeeId_SsnOrderByFNameDesc(int empId, String ssn);

// However let's say I want to order by start_date desc, I am not able to create the right method name here.
}
```

My question is in the comment above: How do I order by or sort using an attribute present in the embedded id class by leveraging JPA's capability like the method that sorts by first name as shown above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<EmployeeEntity> findByEmployeeId_EmpIdAndEmployeeId_SsnOrderByEmployeeIdStartDateDesc(int empId, String ssn);
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to name the query the way you define it in your class.
In following `EmployeeId` is type of the embedded id and name of the property is `startDate` that you want to do order by.

So use `OrderByEmployeeIdStartDateDesc`.